# Ecto Fragment interpolating var in group_by

Tags: sql, postgresql, elixir, ecto

I am trying to the following:

```
query =
  from s in State,
    group_by:
      fragment("date_part(?, ?)", ^group, s.timestamp_start),
    select:
      {fragment("date_part(?, ?)", ^group, s.timestamp_start), count(s.id)}
Repo.all(query)
```

Where `group` might be one of [`'minute'`, `'hour'`, `'day'`].

However, I get the following error:

> ERROR 42803 (grouping_error) column "s0.timestamp_start" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

But if I add `s.timestamp_start` to `group_by` clause, I don't get the expected result, since dates are grouped by `timestamp_start` and not by the part defined.

How can I do this without having to specify a query to each `group` possibility (passing the literal value inside `fragment`) ?

Comment: What is `fragment` ?

Comment: @Minh-Khang https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html?#fragment/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54494557/using-fragment-group-by-together-with-postgres-ecto).

You can use `as` in fragments to reference eachother:

```
    from(m in Message,,
      group_by: fragment("timestamp"),
      select: fragment("date_trunc(?, ?) as timestamp", ^timeseries, m.inserted_at)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do group by, everything you select has to be related to the group by, or use one of the aggregation functions.  Since you're grouping by year, month, etc, the DB wouldn't know which timestamp_start to show in that row.  If you want to show all of the timestamps for that particular row, you can use a fragment that builds out what would end up being `string_agg(s.timestamp_start, ',')`

Comment: Could you explain how ```string_agg``` would be used in the code above?

Comment: oooooh maan, I need this also and no explanation. Too bad.